# Highchart duplicates data on chart instead of refreshing it

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highcharts library to collect data from a csv file every 2 minutes and dispaly it in the graph.

Instead of refreshing the data, the function just duplicates the data and my browser ends up crashing. Can some one help ? i am running out of ideas. Below is my code. I have removed all the xAxis,Yaxis,legend from the code to make it shorter

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var chart;
 var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
    events: {
        load: function() {
            setInterval(function(){
            refresh('file.csv');
            }, 120000);
        }
    }
   },
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' Views'
},
legend: {
    layout: 'left'

},        
 series : []
     };

    function refresh(file) {
    if(chart) chart.destroy();
    $.get(file, function(data) {
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');
            var series = {
            data: []
        };
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo == 0) {
                series.name = item;
            } else {
                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
            }
        });

        options.series.push(series);


   });

   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
   });




   }

  $(document).ready(function() {

refresh('file.csv');

});


</script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Can some one please let me know what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of destroy chart, you can use setData / addSeries function which allows to manipulate data. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData

Comment: i am already using the series.push function which i guess does the same thing like the functions you mentionned. With the code i posted, the chart loads fine but when it refreshes the old data doesnt go away. it's just added to the chart and it breaks everything

Comment: Nope, because push add element to array without redraw.

Comment: do you have an example of what you are suggesting ? i have been trying with both addpseries and setData. But i get errors like chart is not defined or setData is not a function

Comment: Examples of using both functions, are available in related links (above).